# Finding most common values for all columns

Tags: mysql

Below is what I have in table myTable.

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|   date   | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6  | 
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|2015-05-01|   2    |   10   |   20   |   1    |   40   |   50    |
|2015-05-02|   5    |   12   |   22   |   32   |   42   |   52    |
|2015-05-03|   6    |   1    |   24   |   34   |   2    |   5     |
|2015-05-04|   8    |   16   |   26   |   36   |   46   |   56    |
|2015-05-05|   1    |   18   |   28   |   38   |   48   |   58    |
|2015-05-06|   3    |   11   |   1    |   31   |   41   |   51    |
|2015-05-07|   5    |   13   |   23   |   3    |   43   |   53    |
|2015-05-08|   9    |   15   |   25   |   35   |   45   |   55    |
|2015-05-09|   4    |   3    |   27   |   37   |   47   |   3     |
|2015-05-10|   2    |   19   |   29   |   1    |   49   |   59    |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

This output, I wanted to get. But how?

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|      Output all table          |        Output last 5 days      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|     number 1 (5 times)         |       number 1 (3 times)       |
|     number 3 (4 times)         |       number 2 (2 times)       |
|     number 2 (3 times)         |       number 5 (2 times)       |
|     number 5 (3 times)         |                                |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Can I achieve this in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Steps(could help):

1) Decide all the columns you want to consider for similar values. 
2) Create group by column values with count to create an array(value=>count,...) 
3) Once all the array created. Merge them all to create final array. (Add up the count to get the final count)

Answer (score 0):

Having columns in a table that are distinguished only by numbers at the end of the column names generally indicates a problem with the data structure.  In general, you want one row per date and value, in something called a junction table.

You can do what you want by unpivoting the data and then aggregating the results:

```
select value, count(*)
from ((select date, value1 as value from mytable) union all
      (select date, value2 from mytable) union all
      (select date, value3 from mytable) union all
      (select date, value4 from mytable) union all
      (select date, value5 from mytable) union all
      (select date, value6 from mytable) 
     ) t
group by value
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can add a `where` clause on either the outside query or on all the subqueries if you want the histogram for a particular period.